# Creating a text area that fills the available space

Tags: html, css, textarea, autosize

I want to be able to create a text area that fills an available space.

However because of the different monitor resolutions I don't think I can simple specify a character width. Is there anyway of getting around this without having too much logic to specify different character widths for each set of monitor resolutions.

Comment: What about language/platform? Is it html or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea style='width:100%; height:100%'>type here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to simple set

```
style="width: 100%"
```

instead of

```
cols="XX"
```

Comment: how does this take care of height?

Comment: The cols and rows attributes are still needed for standards compliance.

Comment: @Scott, the div doesnt't have a height, so I used an appropriate value or my situation.